# RXJS failing with nested switchmap

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I have a function which returns an observable of some firebase collections which I want to subscribe to. It works fine without the code in-between the commented area but if this is added the observable returns nothing. I've been over this code multiple times but can't figure out why it's failing. Any ideas?

```
 watchFilesPages (businessId, jobId) {
    console.log('watchFilePages called with');
    console.log(businessId);
    console.log(jobId);
    const filesCollection =
    this._firestore
    .collection('clients')
    .doc(businessId)
    .collection('jobs')
    .doc(jobId)
    .collection('uploadedDocuments');
    const pagesResult = filesCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })),
      switchMap((files: any[]) => {
        const pages$ = files.map((f) =>
          this._firestore
          .collection('clients')
          .doc(businessId)
          .collection('jobs')
          .doc(jobId)
          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
          .doc(f.id)
          .collection('pages')
          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            })),
            switchMap((pages: any[]) => {
              const aAreas$ = pages.map((p) =>
                this._firestore
                .collection('clients')
                .doc(businessId)
                .collection('jobs')
                .doc(jobId)
                .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                .doc(f.id)
                .collection('pages')
                .doc(p.id)
                .collection('aAreas', ref => {
                    return ref
                      .orderBy('dateModified', 'desc');
                  })
                .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                  })),
                ),
              );
              const bAreas$ = pages.map((p) =>
                this._firestore
                .collection('clients')
                .doc(businessId)
                .collection('jobs')
                .doc(jobId)
                .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                .doc(f.id)
                .collection('pages')
                .doc(p.id)
                .collection('bAreas', ref => {
                    return ref
                      .orderBy('dateModified', 'desc');
                  })
                .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                  })),
                  ///////////////////////////////// code causing problems start ///////
                  switchMap((bAreas: any[]) => {
                    const aa$ = bAreas.map((b) =>
                      this._firestore
                          .collection('clients')
                          .doc(businessId)
                          .collection('jobs')
                          .doc(jobId)
                          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                          .doc(f.id)
                          .collection('pages')
                          .doc(p.id)
                          .collection('bAreas')
                          .doc(b.id)
                          .collection('aa')
                          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                              return { id, ...data };
                            })),
                          ),
                    );
                    const bb$ = bAreas.map((d) =>
                      this._firestore
                          .collection('clients')
                          .doc(businessId)
                          .collection('jobs')
                          .doc(jobId)
                          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                          .doc(f.id)
                          .collection('pages')
                          .doc(p.id)
                          .collection('bAreas')
                          .doc(d.id)
                          .collection('bb')
                          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                              return { id, ...data };
                            })),
                          ),
                    );
                    // passing the products value down the chain
                    return combineLatest([of(bAreas), combineLatest(aa$), combineLatest(bb$)]);
                  }),
                  map(([bAreas, aa, bb]) =>
                    bAreas.map((d2, idx) => {
                      d2.aa = aa[idx];
                      d2.bb = bb[idx];
                      return d2;
                    }),
                  ),
                  ///////////////////////////////// code causing problems end ///////
                ),
              );
              // passing the products value down the chain
              return combineLatest([of(pages), combineLatest(aAreas$), combineLatest(bAreas$)]);
            }),
            map(([pages, aAreas, bAreas]) =>
              pages.map((p2, idx) => {
                p2.aAreas = aAreas[idx];
                p2.bAreas = bAreas[idx];
                return p2;
              }),
            ),
          ),
        );
        return combineLatest([of(files), combineLatest(pages$)]);
      }),
      map(([files, pages]) =>
        files.map((f2, idx) => {
          f2.pages = pages[idx];
          return f2;
        }),
      ),
    );
    console.log('pagesResult');
    console.log(pagesResult);
    return pagesResult;
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone running into this issue here is the solution...

I needed to modify the nested combineLatest operators to accommodate the possibility of nested arrays with zero length.

```
array.length ? array : [of([])])
```

Here is the modified, now working code...

```
watchFilesPages (businessId, jobId) {
    console.log('watchFilePages called with');
    console.log(businessId);
    console.log(jobId);
    const filesCollection =
    this._firestore
    .collection('clients')
    .doc(businessId)
    .collection('jobs')
    .doc(jobId)
    .collection('uploadedDocuments');
    const pagesResult = filesCollection.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })),
      switchMap((files: any[]) => {
        const pages$ = files.map((f) =>
          this._firestore
          .collection('clients')
          .doc(businessId)
          .collection('jobs')
          .doc(jobId)
          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
          .doc(f.id)
          .collection('pages')
          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            })),
            switchMap((pages: any[]) => {
              const aAreas$ = pages.map((p) =>
                this._firestore
                .collection('clients')
                .doc(businessId)
                .collection('jobs')
                .doc(jobId)
                .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                .doc(f.id)
                .collection('pages')
                .doc(p.id)
                .collection('aAreas', ref => {
                    return ref
                      .orderBy('dateModified', 'desc');
                  })
                .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                  })),
                ),
              );
              const bAreas$ = pages.map((p) =>
                this._firestore
                .collection('clients')
                .doc(businessId)
                .collection('jobs')
                .doc(jobId)
                .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                .doc(f.id)
                .collection('pages')
                .doc(p.id)
                .collection('bAreas', ref => {
                    return ref
                      .orderBy('dateModified', 'desc');
                  })
                .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                  })),
                  ///////////////////////////////// code causing problems start ///////
                  switchMap((bAreas: any[]) => {
                    const aa$ = bAreas.map((b) =>
                      this._firestore
                          .collection('clients')
                          .doc(businessId)
                          .collection('jobs')
                          .doc(jobId)
                          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                          .doc(f.id)
                          .collection('pages')
                          .doc(p.id)
                          .collection('bAreas')
                          .doc(b.id)
                          .collection('aa')
                          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                              return { id, ...data };
                            })),
                          ),
                    );
                    const bb$ = bAreas.map((d) =>
                      this._firestore
                          .collection('clients')
                          .doc(businessId)
                          .collection('jobs')
                          .doc(jobId)
                          .collection('uploadedDocuments')
                          .doc(f.id)
                          .collection('pages')
                          .doc(p.id)
                          .collection('bAreas')
                          .doc(d.id)
                          .collection('bb')
                          .snapshotChanges().pipe(
                            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                              return { id, ...data };
                            })),
                          ),
                    );
                    // passing the products value down the chain
                    return combineLatest([of(bAreas), combineLatest(aa$.length ? aa$ : [of([])])), combineLatest(bb$.length ? bb$ : [of([])]))]);
                  }),
                  map(([bAreas, aa, bb]) =>
                    bAreas.map((d2, idx) => {
                      d2.aa = aa[idx];
                      d2.bb = bb[idx];
                      return d2;
                    }),
                  ),
                  ///////////////////////////////// code causing problems end ///////
                ),
              );
              // passing the products value down the chain
              return combineLatest([of(pages), combineLatest(aAreas$.length ? aAreas$ : [of([])])), combineLatest(bAreas$.length ? bAreas$ : [of([])]))]);
            }),
            map(([pages, aAreas, bAreas]) =>
              pages.map((p2, idx) => {
                p2.aAreas = aAreas[idx];
                p2.bAreas = bAreas[idx];
                return p2;
              }),
            ),
          ),
        );
        return combineLatest([of(files), combineLatest(pages$.length ? pages$ : [of([])]))]);
      }),
      map(([files, pages]) =>
        files.map((f2, idx) => {
          f2.pages = pages[idx];
          return f2;
        }),
      ),
    );
    console.log('pagesResult');
    console.log(pagesResult);
    return pagesResult;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting this:

```
return combineLatest([of(bAreas), combineLatest(aa$), combineLatest(bb$)]);
```

to this:

```
return combineLatest([of(bAreas), aa$, bb$]);
```

and the other lines where you have similar nested `combineLatest`.

From the map function it looks like `aAreas` and `bAreas` are arrays, but `combineLatest` will wrap those into yet another array, so you get them as arrays of arrays.

Not sure this is causing the problem, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, after trying the problem still persists.